# C# extension method to get list of string from list of customObject

Tags: c#

```
class Person
{
    string Name
}
```

With a `List<Person> persons`, what's the extension method to get `List<string>` object with each person's Name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really need a `List<string>`, then you can use:

```
persons.Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
```

But if you only need to enumerate over the values, you can drop the `ToList()`:

```
persons.Select(p => p.Name);
```

Comment: @OP Don't forget you might not need the ToList if you're only going to be iterating over it.

Comment: If you skip the ToList then if the underlying Person objects change so will the names in your enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

using an extention method:

```
static class PersonListExtensions
{
    public static List<string> ToStringList( this List<Person> persons)
    {
        return persons.Select(p=>p.Name).ToList();
    }
}
```